# List records with duplicate values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table on sql server 2008:

```
projectdetailId|projectId|recordTypeID|value|auditDate
1|100|1|abc|10-01-2014|
2|100|1|abc|10-01-2014|
3|100|1|def|10-01-2014|
4|200|1|mno|23-01-2014
...
...
```

I need to extract the `projectID` with repeated values,along with the values themselves, for records greater than 01-01-2014.
So,in the above case:

```
100,IDs=abc
```

I do the following:

```
select
     projectId,
     IDs = STUFF(
    (SELECT ','+ CAST(g2.[value] AS VARCHAR(255)) 
      FROM ProjectDetail g2
      WHERE g2.recordType=1
            and g1.value=g2.value
            and g1.recordType=g2.recordType
            and g1.projectId=g2.projectIdand
            and g2.auditDate > '01-01-2014'
      For XML PATH('')
      ),1,1,'')
FROM ProjectDetail g1
GROUP BY projectId
having COUNT(*) > 1
```

I get the following error:

```
Column 'value' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Column 'recordType' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Do you have table `Projects`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have table `Projects` then you can correct your query as follows:

```
select
     projectId,
     IDs = STUFF(
    (SELECT ','+ CAST(g2.[value] AS VARCHAR(255)) as 'data()' 
      FROM ProjectDetail g2
      WHERE g2.recordType=1
            and g1.value=g2.value
            and g1.recordType=g2.recordType
            and g1.projectId=g2.projectIdand
            and g2.auditDate > '01-01-2014'
      For XML PATH('')
      ),1,1,'')
FROM Projects P
WHERE EXISTS (select projectID
              from ProjectDetail PD ON P.projectID=PD.ProjectID
              having count(*)>1)
```

OR without table `Projects`

```
   select
         projectId,
         IDs = STUFF(
        (SELECT ','+ CAST(g2.[value] AS VARCHAR(255)) as 'data()' 
          FROM ProjectDetail g2
          WHERE g2.recordType=1
                and g1.value=g2.value
                and g1.recordType=g2.recordType
                and g1.projectId=g2.projectIdand
                and g2.auditDate > '01-01-2014'
          For XML PATH('')
          ),1,1,'')
    FROM  (select projectID
           from ProjectDetail PD
           having count(*)>1) P
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
SELECT DISTINCT projectId, 
SUBSTRING((SELECT ', ' + value 
FROM dbo.#temp g2 
WHERE g2.recordTypeID=10 
and g1.value=g2.value 
and g2.projectId = g1.projectId 
and g2.auditDate > '01-01-2014' FOR XML PATH('')), 3, 8000) 
FROM dbo.ProjectDetail g1 WHERE projectId IN 
(SELECT projectId FROM ProjectDetail a GROUP BY projectId HAVING COUNT(projectId) > 1)
```